# Sobre integridade em bd mysql

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Se eu definir no bd as chaves estrangeiras e ativação "cascade" conforme a utilização dos eventos delete e update, preciso fazer isso a nível de aplicação também?

Comment: Você está se referindo a triggers `ON DELETE CASCADE` e `ON UPDATE CASCADE`?

Comment: sim isso mesmo...